# How to fix the error "The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mysql-workbench

hello i just created my application it is still empty i just put a class which allows to connect to my sql database but when i run my application i get the following error:

> AVERTISSEMENT:
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@17460bca
>   -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more
>   than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last
>   acquisition attempt exception: 
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor34.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
>     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:952)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:173)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
>     ... 15 more

here is the code i made :

```
package com.luv2code.testdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestDbServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDbServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // établir la connexion à mysql :

        String user="springstudent";
        String password="springstudent";
        String jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        try {

            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("Connection à  la base de donnée :"+jdbcUrl);

            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection cnx;
            cnx=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password);

            out.println("Success !!!!!!!!!");

            cnx.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I put port 3309 instead of 3306 because port 3306 does not work in my mysqlworkbench it gives me the following error :

[image: error 1]

and even when i want to create a new database with port 3306 it gives me the following error:

[image: error 2]

I do not know if it is this port problem that gives me this error.

help me please !!

Comment: What exact error are you getting when you try to use 127.0.0.1:3306, in your error message it fails when using 127.0.0.1:3309 and it says 3306 is the default which is correct for SQL, so what exactly is the error for 3306?

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly started the SQL server on localhost?

Comment: hello, for that of 3309 it is a database which is already created but I cannot access it and for that of 3306 (I try to create a new database with the prot 3306 but it gives me this error)

Comment: yes @Benny i am sure

Comment: Have you ensured that you granted access to the user to those databases you are trying to access?

Comment: yes i put this in my requet sql GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'springstudent'@'localhost';

Comment: You want to access using hbstudent but you granted the privileges to springstudent? Please check

Comment: you did not understand me, in my application I want to access springstudent but it gives me the error that I mentioned above, but I did not know where the error comes from, and since I know that I have a problem with mysql (port 3306) does not work as well as other functionality I wanted you also show the errors that I have on mysql (like the errors that I showed above where it there is hbstudent) for better help you detected the error. now my goal is to access springstudent thanks to the code that I mentioned above but there is this error which prevents me from doing this